# blender compile 2.78.5 error

Tags: blend-files

i try to compile the latest blender source code, using visual studio 2013, and i get an error in the last stage. If someone did it without problem, can tell me what versions used for each software?

Comment: When you could tell us the error ...

Comment: ok sorry i get this in the end:

Comment: 9>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal

Comment: and this 9>  CMake Error at source/creator/cmake_install.cmake:1643 (file):
9>    file INSTALL cannot find "F:/development/cm/bin/Release/blender.exe".
9>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
9>    cmake_install.cmake:35 (include)

Comment: Questions about compiling blender are too localized and hard to troubleshoot on the format of this site, and are considered off topic (see: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems/400#400)

Comment: Best place to ask about building blender would be `#blendercoders` on IRC.

Comment: You should edit the first entry, and add some screenshots. I have the feeling that some parts are missing.